# webview == null when call again fragment inside viewpager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, webview

I have a problem with `viewpager`. I created 2 fragment inside `viewpager`, but when I call again then I get `view == null`.

**paper_adater.java**

```
public class Paper_adapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
Context context;

public Paper_adapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (arg0) {
    case 0:
        return new Web_fragment();
    case 1:
        return new Table_fragment();
    default:
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 2;
}

@Override
public float getPageWidth(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0.95f;
}
```

**detail_fragment.java**

```
public class DetailFragment extends Fragment implements OnPageChangeListener {
public static final String TAG = "Detail fragment";
WebView webView;
ViewPager viewPaper;
Paper_adapter paper_adapter;
public static int currentPage;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.e(TAG, "on create view");
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail_fragment, null);
    viewPaper = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    paper_adapter = new Paper_adapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    viewPaper.setAdapter(paper_adapter);
    viewPaper.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    return view;
}

public void Draw(String data, int position) {
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    Fragment fr = paper_adapter.getItem(position);
    if (fr instanceof Web_fragment && fr != null) {
        ((Web_fragment) fr).draw(getActivity(),data);
    } else if (fr instanceof Table_fragment && fr != null) {

    }
}

}
```

**Web_fragment.java**

```
public class Web_fragment extends Fragment {

public static final String URL = "file:///android_asset/chart/index.html";
private final String TAG = "WEB fragment";

private WebView webView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.webview_fragment, null);
    this.webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webview);
//  webView.clearHistory();
//  webView.clearCache(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.loadUrl(URL);
    return view;
}

public void setValue(Context context) {
    // webView = (WebView)getView().findViewById(R.id.webview);
    // webView.loadUrl("javascript:setValue()");
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroyView();
}

public Boolean draw(Context context, String data) {
    if (webView == null) {
    //  webView.loadUrl("javascript:setValue()");
        Toast.makeText(context, "webview null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        .show();
    } else {
        if (data == null) {
            webView = (WebView) getView().findViewById(R.id.webview);
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:setValue()");
            return false;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "data web :" + data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:setValue()");
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

When I call `Draw()` from `detail_fragment` then I get `Web_fragment == null`

Comment: obviously you don't know android basics: fragment's lifecycle ... your getItem implementation of adapter returns new instance of fragment every time ... this fragment is not added to any fragment manager (it doesn't start its lifecycle at all) ... **obviously such fragment has no view** ... even without knowledge about fragment's lifecycle should be obvious that it has no view ... why? because only fragment constructor was called and there was no call which creates view(onCreateView)

Comment: How do i create it ? please help me . OR send tutorial . thank you.

Comment: i did it, thank you.